# Spring validation request body as string

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, endpoint

I have endpoint with request body as `String`object, which contains a phone number:

```
@PostMapping("/phone-number") 
public Response phoneNumberRequest(@RequestBody @Valid @Pattern(regexp="myRegexp") String phoneNumber) {
...
}
```

I have just one request parameter `phoneNumber`, so I don't need a JSON object.
I need to validate a phone number. But `@Valid` annotation doesn't work with `@Pattern(regexp = "myRegexp")` when request body is the simple `String` object. So my question is why? How can I validate phone number in this case?

Comment: What is your request body in json ? may be you should create a request body class and use @Valid to validate using before requestbody

Comment: You need to use `@Valid` annotation, and as far as @Pattern is concerned, you can use `@Pattern(regexp = "YOUR_REGEX")`

Comment: I have just one request parameter `phoneNumber`, so I don't need json object. `@Valid` annotation doesn't work with `@Pattern(regexp = "YOUR_REGEX")` when reqest body is simple `String` object. So my question is why? How can I validate phone number in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
@PostMapping("{phone-number}")
public Response phoneNumberRequest(
  @PathVariable String phone-number) {

  Boolean valid = phone-number.matches("your-regex");
  ...

}
```